# remove formarray element reactive forms angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to remove an array element from an formArray in angular reactive form as i dont want to display empty array element. I need to remove the element whose all controls contain null value or false. I dont want to remove the element even if any of its control contains a value other that the once specified.

this.accounts is formArray. I am trying to use the object.keys but not able to retrieve the element that does not contain values

I have tried something below. Could you

```
  if(this.readonly) {
      for (const control of this.accounts.controls) {
       const result  =  Object.keys(control).find((key) => (control[key] != null || true));
       if(!result) {
       // this.accounts.controls.splice();
       }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the control. You can just access the value on that control.

```
if(this.readonly) {
   for (const control of this.accounts.controls) {
     const result  =  control.value != null;
     if(!result) {
       // this.accounts.controls.splice();
     }
   }
}
```

Also instead of splice(). I would suggest using removeAt() on the the formArray it self. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#removeat

Because after splice you would also have to call updateValueAndValidity for the change detection to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
(<FormArray>this.accounts).controls.forEach((el, i) => {
    if(el.value === null || el.value === false) {
(<FormArray>this.accounts.controls).removeAt(i);
 }
})
```

We can run a loop of controls and check for value of each control. As it is a formarray, looping in this way over the controls works without any issue

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?